# I am unable to implement the methods in the wsdl link class it don't consists any client class

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

My service provider provided me a web service descriptive language link(WSDL) and asked me to call the methods from the client class, but I didn't find any client class.

I used eclipse and dynamic web project for extracting the file of the web service descriptive language link. I have tried to create a class of my own and tried to call the methods of the classes they provided to me but nothing worked for me.